# Decoding JSON to class then inserting into an MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have a php function that creates a JSON array which is then posted to my web service. The function works fine, but the web service is giving me some issues.

I am using json_decode to decode the string passed in, and the assigning the values to the class. This is working fine. I'm using the following to decode and then assign to my class

```
$obj = json_decode($json, true);
$classObj = new AppointmentList();
foreach ($obj  as $key => $value)
    $classObj->{$key} = $value;

var_dump($json);
var_dump($obj);
var_dump($classObj);
```

The dump gives me this

`array(1) { ["AppointmentList"]=> array(10) { ["id"]=> string(0) "" ["MeetingId"]=> NULL ["MeetingName"]=> string(7) "derwent" ["DateTimeFrom"]=> string(13) "20th Oct 2016" ["Length"]=> string(0) "" ["Room"]=> string(4) "gere" ["Venue"]=> string(4) "gere" ["DateCreated"]=> string(10) "2016-10-20" ["DateDue"]=> string(10) "2016-10-20" ["UserId"]=> string(9) "JohnsonPa" } }`

`object(AppointmentList)#1 (11) { ["id"]=> string(0) "" ["MeetingId"]=> string(0) "" ["MeetingName"]=> string(0) "" ["DateTimeFrom"]=> string(0) "" ["Length"]=> string(0) "" ["Room"]=> string(0) "" ["Venue"]=> string(0) "" ["DateCreated"]=> string(0) "" ["DateDue"]=> string(0) "" ["UserId"]=> string(0) ""`

`["AppointmentList"]=> array(10) { ["id"]=> string(0) "" ["MeetingId"]=> NULL ["MeetingName"]=> string(7) "derwent" ["DateTimeFrom"]=> string(13) "20th Oct 2016" ["Length"]=> string(0) "" ["Room"]=> string(4) "gere" ["Venue"]=> string(4) "gere" ["DateCreated"]=> string(10) "2016-10-20" ["DateDue"]=> string(10) "2016-10-20" ["UserId"]=> string(9) "JohnsonPa" } }`

The appointment list is populated.

My issue though is getting this data out to put it into an SQL query. I've tried a whole raft of different ways to get the data out ($classObj->AppointmentList->MeetingName, $classObj.['MeetingName'] etc etc etc) and it either gives me an error about using an array or nothing at all shows.

How do I get this data out to insert into an SQL query? My current one (which is incorrect) looks like this

```
$query = "REPLACE INTO AppointmentList (id, MeetingId, MeetingName, DateTimeFrom, Length, Room, Venue, DateCreated, DateDue, UserId) VALUES (".$classObj['id'].", ".$classObj['MeetingId'].", '".$classObj['MeetingName']."', '".$classObj['DateTimeFrom']."', ".$classObj['Length'].", '".$classObj['Room']."', '".$classObj['Venue'].", STR_TO_DATE(".$classObj['DateCreated'].", '%Y%m%d'), STR_TO_DATE(".$classObj['DateDue'].", '%Y%m%d'), '".$classObj['UserId']."');";
```

Comment: Please, under all circumstances, take the time to read https://xkcd.com/327/ and http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

If possible, do more research, but nevertheless: Don't deploy your code to any internet server before you've sanitized it. Thank you!

Comment: I'll also gift you an upvote, should you change your script to using PDO and prepared statements: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: The code is sanitised well before it gets to this stage :)

Answer (score 0):

I think in your `$query` instead of `$classObj['Venue']` it should be `$classObj['AppointmentList']['Venue']`

Comment: You think? Are you not sure?

Comment: I do think and I'm not sure

Answer (score 0):

Your $classObj is an object, not an array. In your class 'AppointmentList' you should define some methods to get the attributes you're setting in your loop.

Then when you insert this information into your database, you can access it like this:

```
$query = "REPLACE INTO AppointmentList (id, MeetingId,...etc...) VALUES ('"$classObj->get_id()."', ".$classObj->get_MeetingId()."');";
```

Make an array to put your objects inside of if you're going to have more than one of them. Then you could load them into your database like this:

```
for($i=0; $i<sizeof($somearray);$i++){
$query = "REPLACE INTO AppointmentList (id, MeetingId,...etc...) VALUES ('"$somearray[$i]->get_id()."', ".$somearray[$i]->get_MeetingId()."');"; 
//SQL PDO insertion here
```

}